# How to fix this bug on sorting an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T sortArray(T data[])
{
  int arrsize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(T);
  int x,y,temp;
  for(y=0;y<arrsize;y++)
  {
     for(x =0;x<arrsize-y-1;x++)
     {

         if(data[x]>data[x+1])
         {
             temp = data[x];
             data[x] = data[x+1];
             data[x+1] = temp;

         }
    }

 }

 return  data;

}

int main()
{
   int x;
   int arr[] = {10,7,32,65,12,6};
   int sorted[] = sortArray(arr[]);
   for(x=0;x<6;x++)
   {
       cout<<sorted[x]<<endl;
   }
}
```

When i try to sort compile this code i get an error of

```
**abc\main.cpp:34: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
 int sorted[] = sortArray(arr[]);
                              ^**
```

How to fix this bug . if i remove **[]** i get more errors

Comment: And this other errors are? Because, without [] is correct.

Comment: No actually without it there are lot more errors coming up

Comment: *And this other errors are...?*

Comment: @Optimuskck, More errors doesn't mean the `[]` isn't wrong.

Comment: Do note that `sizeof(data)/sizeof(T)` will NOT give you the number of elements in the array. `data` is a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a lot wrong. Fixed it here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T* sortArray(T data[], int arrsize)  // better pass the size of the array, and return T*
{
  int x,y,temp;
  for(y=0;y<arrsize;y++)
  {
     for(x =0;x<arrsize-y-1;x++)
     {

         if(data[x]>data[x+1])
         {
             temp = data[x];
             data[x] = data[x+1];
             data[x+1] = temp;

         }
    }
 }

 return  data;

}

int main()
{
   int x;
   int arr[6] = {10,7,32,65,12,6};
   int *sorted = sortArray(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); // pass size of array
   for(x=0;x<6;x++)
   {
       cout<<sorted[x]<<endl;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
6
7
10
12
32
65
```

Comment: Thank you very much floris . i found the errors here. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
T sortArray(T data[])
```

is supposed to return a `T`, but you are useing an `int` array to catch it:

```
int sorted[] = sortArray(arr[]);
```

---

To work out, you can change this method to (you don't need to return it, i.e. removing the `return` line):

```
void sortArray(T data[])
```

and call it like:

```
sortArray<int>(arr);
```

Comment: Yeah but T is a template right? in compile time the Compiler identified T as an "int" type array right?

Comment: @Optimuskck No. If you call it like `sortArray<int>(...)`, `T` will be `int`, not `int` array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yeah i am sorry. so we are using the casting to convert the array into integer type.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `sortArray` is `T` but what you return is `data` of type `T[]`. You should change to the following prototype:

```
T* sortArray(T data[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing bubble sort.

You need to fix the method signature as follows:

T * sortArray(T * data)
   {

In the main(), you need to fix the calls:
   int * sorted = sortArray(arr);

This should fix the errors. Basically, you are sending in a pointer to an array, and you want the method to return a pointer to a sorted array.